# Sed function with arithmetic

Tags: bash, sed

i am doing up a program that if the user enter a number,(that number refer to item quantity being sold). The programme will then  automatically update the available quantity and sold quantity and reflect back to user.

I would also like to know if there is a way to prevent user enter a integer that is bigger that the int store in "$avilable" variable

Thank you

The output will be as shown below.

```
Title : Star Wars VI – Return of the Jedi
Author : Darth Vader
No. of copies sold  : 3
Current book  info :    
Star Wars VI – Return of the Jedi, Darth Vader, $8.05,  30, 20 

New book info :     
Star Wars VI – Return of the Jedi, Darth Vader, $8.05,  27, 23
```

Below is my code, however i am facing difficulty as it is not working.

```
 {
    echo -n "Title: "  
    read title
    echo -n "Author: "
    read author
    echo -n "No. of copies sold: "
    read numsold 
    if [[ ! $numsold|| $numsold = *[^0-9]* ]]; then
    echo "Please input a number." >&2
    fi
    newavilable=$((avilable - numsold)) 
    newsold=$((sold + numsold))
    sed "s/${sold}/${newsold}/g" BookDB.txt > BookDB1.txt
    mv -f BookDB1.txt BookDB.txt
    sed "s/${avilable}/${newavilable}/g" BookDB.txt > BookDB1.txt
    mv -f BookDB1.txt BookDB.txt
    echo $title:$author:$price:$avilable:$sold >> BookDB.txt
}
```

Comment: `sed "s/${avilable}/${newavilable}g"` should be `sed "s/${avilable}/${newavilable}/g"` ( missed last `/` in this expression ).

Comment: Rather than keep moving BookDB1 back over BookDB you can use the `sed -i` flag to do a replacement in the same file. You can also do `sed -e 's/.../.../' -e 's/.../.../' -e 's/.../.../'` to do multiple replacements in one iteration. Far faster than keep opening the file multiple times.

Comment: your sed work only if there is 1 line (1 information in fact) in the BookDB.txt becasue there is no reference to book, just quantity and there could be more than 1 line with the value but for different item.

Comment: If you're going to use `:` as the field separator in your database then you need to make sure the users don't enter a `:` in one of the fields. Right now if someone entered a title as `Dinner: A Love Story` then your database would be corrupted. I would recommend you don't use `:` to separate fields but use tab instead since a book title should not contain a tab character and so it's easy to test for and reject or modify. Also, you should really be using awk for the text manipulation part of this, not a series of sed commands.

Answer (score 1):

I would proceed like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
info=""
# while $info is not set
while [[ -z "$info" ]] ; do
    # Get at title
    title=""
    while [[ -z "$title" ]] ; do
        echo -n "Title: "
        read title
    done

    # Get an author
    author=""
    while [[ -z "$author" ]] ; do
        echo -n "Author: "
        read author
    done

    # Check book is in DB
    info=$(grep "^${title}:${author}:" BookDB.txt)
    if [[ -z "$info" ]] ; then
        echo "Not in database."
    fi
done

# Extract number of books available/already sold
avilable="$(cut -d: -f4 <<< $info)"
sold="$(cut -d: -f5 <<< $info)"

# Get number of recently sold books
while [[ -z "$numsold" ]] ; do
    # We want a number…
    while [[ ! "$numsold" =~ ^[0-9]{1,}$ ]] ; do
        echo -n "No. of copies sold: "
        read numsold
    done
    newavilable=$((avilable - numsold))
    newsold=$((sold + numsold))
    # And we want it lower than $newavilable
    if [[ $newavilable -lt 0 ]] ; then
        echo "Too high"
        numsold=""
    fi
done

# Print old info
echo "Current book info:"
echo "$info"

# Currently prints desired new DB
echo "New book info:"
# Add '-i' option to sed to edit BookDB.txt in place instead of printing it
sed -e "s/^\(${title}:${author}:[0-9]\+\):${avilable}:${sold}$/\1:${newavilable}:${newsold}/" \
    BookDB.txt
```

In bash tests, don't forget to surround your variables with double quotes, or you'll have bad surprises when they are empty.

---

**Edit:**
If your price is a float instead of an integer, you can extract it with:

```
price="$(cut -d: -f3 <<< $info)"
```

and replace final `sed` command by either

```
sed -e "s/^\(${title}:${author}:${price}\):${avilable}:${sold}$/\1:${newavilable}:${newsold}/" BookDB.txt
#               extracted value ^^^^^^^^
```

or

```
sed -e "s/^\(${title}:${author}:[0-9.]\+\):${avilable}:${sold}$/\1:${newavilable}:${newsold}/" BookDB.txt
#                       added a dot ^
```

As bash does not handle floats, use something like `bc` (or `dc`, or perl/python/…) to perform operations, *e.g.* something like:

```
totalprice=$(echo "$unitprice * $numsold" | bc)
```

Comment: Hi, your code does not accept more than 1 word. For example if i key in (title : happy day) and (author: mary ann) i will get an output error: `Title: happy day
Author: mary ann
grep: day:mary: No such file or directory
grep: ann:: No such file or directory
No. of copies sold: 10
./ps.sh: line 37: 12.99: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".99")
Current book info:
BookDB.txt:happy day:mary ann:12.99:197:101
New book info:
Catch Me If You Can:mary ann:23.60:6:2
happy day:mary ann:12.99:197:101`

Comment: I change the coding line `info="$(grep ^${title}:${author}: BookDB.txt)"` into ` grep -F "^$title:$author" BookDB.txt | $info` but it still could not work. Appreciate your guidance

Comment: Sorry you're right, I made a mistake. You got the idea and nearly the fix: the line should be `info=$(grep "^${title}:${author}:" BookDB.txt)`. I'll edit my post immediately.

Comment: (Also, just in case: with your current DB format, my script will probably break if your title/author fields contain colons `:` as `cut` commands will fail to get correct values).

Comment: Hi, i guess it just luck. im still very new to shell and is still learning a lot. Im really grateful for your help. Actually there are still two more issues with the coding. The first one is that if there is a float in the line e.g `a:b:*1.00*:100:200, the arithmetic operation will not take place.
Title: a
Author: b
No. of copies sold: 1
Current book info:
a:b:1.00:100:200
New book info:
a:b:1.00:100:200
i am still trying to find out the reason

Comment: For this first issue: bash does not handle float numbers (see `man bash` or [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137110/comparison-of-decimal-numbers-in-bash/137114) for details). You might want to convert your numbers into integers, or use `bc` (`echo "7.56-3.54" | bc`), or `dc` (`echo "7.56 3.54 - p" | dc`), or use python, etc.

Comment: Ok thanks, i will research more, i am not sure as to the second question on saving the new info into my DB. Even though if it can perform the arithmetic opertation but it will not save into the DB file. May i know is this a bug or you code it this way? If that is how you intent to code then it good, i will read up and make the changes accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your second question correctly. Do you mean my code does not save output into database? I did it on purpose so that you could see what's the output without deleting things. Now if you want to directly save output of final `sed` command instead of printing it, you can use `-i` option, _i.e._ replace `sed -e "…" BookDB.txt` by `sed -i -e "…" BookDB.txt`. Does it answer to your question?

Comment: Hi, yes you got it.I thought "-i" refer to case insensitive

Comment: Not here. For information, `i` with `sed` is for “case-insensitive” when used after a substitution, like this: `sed 's/pattern/substitute/i' input_file.txt`.

Comment: I have made changes to code ` newavilable=$((avilable - numsold))
    newsold=$((sold + numsold))` to  `newavilable=$(echo scale=3;"($avilable)-($numsold)" |bc) 
    newsold=$(echo scale=3;"($sold)+($numsold)" |bc)` however it's still not work due to the "price field" is a float and not the "available/numsold" field. I decided to play around to make the price field to bc so i am not sure after making the price field to bc, how can i combine it to the sed. `sed -e "s/^\(${title}:${author}:[0-9]\+\):${avilable}:${sold}$/\1:${newavilable}:${newsold}/" \
    BookDB.txt`

Comment: so i added in `# Converting the price field to float 
price=$(cut -d ":" -f 3 BookDB.txt |bc)` before # Print old info. Then i change the sed `sed -e "s/^\(${title}:${author}:[0-9]\+\):${avilable}:${sold}$/\1:${newavilable}:${newsold}/" \
    BookDB.txt` to `sed -e "s/^\(${title}:${author}:${price}:[0-9]\+\):${avilable}:${sold}$/\1:${newavilable}:${newsold}/" \
    BookDB.tx`. However i am not sure if that is right?

Comment: Hmm… 1st question (convert `$newavilable` to float): if either `$avilable` or `$numsold` is a float, piping difference to `bc` (as you do) should be enough. If both are integers, `bc` should return an integer as well. In this case, you could just do `$newavilable="$((avilable - numsold)).00"`. Now for 2nd question: you forgot to remove `:[0-9]\+` which was representing the price already, so you should rather have `sed -e "s/^\(${title}:${author}:${price}\):${avilable}:${sold}$/\1:${newavilabl‌​e}:${newsold}/" BookDB.txt`. But your price won't be changed to float.

Comment: Globally I think you should have floats for your prices in your database from start (you could convert all integer prices once and for all with something like `sed 's/^\([^:]*:[^:*]:[0-9]\+\):/\1.00/' BookDB.txt`, note that I didn't test it). Then when you have to modify a price, just do it through `bc`, it should remain a float. You could of course do something similar with the other figures of your database; but are you sure it's relevant to represent a number of available books with a float instead of an integer?

Comment: Hi, i am grateful for your help. My program have 7 function and this is a subset of my main program so i want use the bc to convert the price to float. Maybe the logic flawed output can explain better.
`Title: a
Author: b
No. of copies sold: 10
Current book info:
a:b:1.00:53:247
New book info:
a:b:1.00:53:247`
where the new book info should have changes, and i guess it has to do with the "1.00"
i will post my new coding as answer instead. Please give me your guidance.

Comment: I think that's because `[0-9]\+` is only matching figures (no dot), hence integers. Replace it by `[0-9.]\+` and you should have your modification.